Native Node.js Metrics in Application Insights
I have installed the applicationinsights-native-metrics package mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs
I assume my app is generating metrics mentioned in the article but I can't quite figure out how to view them in Application Insights. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
It was suggested to me that I should be seeing a new namespace in the Metrics Explorer in Application Insights called "Node.js Extended Metrics" but I don't see this.
The documentation says you just need to install the package.   After that didn't work, I tried explicitly requiring it in the app.  Neither worked.

You can check the application insights in the Transaction Search.Image

@Matt Brown Even I didn't find this namespace Node.js Extended Metrics after Installing applicationinsights-native-metrics package in the code.

@Aslesha Kantamsetti   Interesting - thanks for the reply.   If that's the case I'm unsure how to get to the metrics this package supposedly collects.

@Matt Brown Are you looking for this?

@AsleshaKantamsetti it could be that.  What's the full namespace name there and how did you get it to pull through?

@Matt Brown Full name of Namespace is azure.appinsights, I got this with code and native metrics package.

By using the below code and applicationinsights-native-metrics package, I generated the metrics as mentioned in this document.
I ran the below commands to install the packages.
npm install applicationinsights
npm install applicationinsights-native-metrics

server.js:
 let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
 let http = require("http");
 const connectionString = '<ConnectionString>';
 appInsights.setup(connectionString).start(); 
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 let client = appInsights.defaultClient;
 client.trackEvent({ name: "my custom event", properties: { customProperty: "custom property value" } });
 client.trackException({ exception: new Error("handled exceptions can be logged with this method") });
 client.trackMetric({ name: "custom metric", value: 3 });
 client.trackTrace({ message: "trace message" });
 client.trackDependency({
   target: "http://dbname",
   name: "select customers proc",
   data: "SELECT * FROM Customers",
   duration: 231,
   resultCode: 0,
   success: true,
   dependencyTypeName: "ZSQL"
 });
 client.trackRequest({
   name: "GET /customers",
   url: "http://myserver/customers",
   duration: 309,
   resultCode: 200,
   success: true
 });
 http.createServer((req, res) => {
   client.trackNodeHttpRequest({ request: req, response: res });
   if (req.url === '/customers') {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: "Customers endpoint" }));
   } else {
     res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
     res.end("Not Found");
   }
 }).listen(port, () => {
   console.log('Server is running on port '+port);
 });

package.json:
{
  "name": "nodeappinsights",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "@azure/opentelemetry-instrumentation-azure-sdk": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.47.1",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "^0.52.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.52.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node": "^1.25.0",
    "applicationinsights": "^2.9.5",
    "applicationinsights-native-metrics": "^0.0.10",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  }
}

After running below command,
node server.js

I could be able to view the logs in Transaction search of Application Insights in Azure Portal as below,


In Application Insights, go to Monitoring section, select Metrics, in Metric Namespace under Custom select azure.applicationinsights as below,

After updating the above metric namespace,you could be able to see the below Metrics.


Thanks for the reply.   Here is what I'm seeing for that namespace: [link]https://imgur.com/a/CpgYBR6
I will try to do some more digging on this later today.

@MattBrown Have you tried my code? Make sure you install the applicationinsights-native-metrics properly, as it is working fine for me.

Yes. An isolated app, installed the 2 packages, used your code exactly (plugging in the connection string).  On the start() call I get a number of warnings/errors:
Module @azure/core-tracing has been loaded before…itialize it before requiring @azure/core-tracing
Error: @opentelemetry/api: Registration of version v1.9.0 for trace does not match previously registered API v1.8.0
'Failed to add SpanProcessors to TracerProvider.',
The metrics look the same as what I posted yesterday.  I'm going to try and minimize the code and dig into some of these errors.

@MattBrown I added  Package.json to the solution, check it once.

Aligning the package versions did the trick.  Thank you so much for the detailed responses.

@MattBrown I'm glad to hear the issue resolved.

For me, just having the applicationinsights version to 2.9.5 worked, i didnt have to add the other dependencies.
I did get the same error using the latest version however.
